# Hiding spin buttons on number input html ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

I am looking for a fail-safe way to hide spin buttons from a number input field in an HTML template for Ionic.

The following HTML code displays an input with spinner buttons:

```
<ion-input type='number'></ion-input>
```

The `type=number` is convenient for mobile, since it triggers the numeric keyboard. But the spinner buttons are too small for a good user experience.

How can I correctly hide them for all browsers/webkits?
Thanks

Comment: Are you refering to the up and down arrows in the number input?

Comment: Yes the up and down arrows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide them in webkit based browsers, add this to your css file:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
}
```

To hide them on Firefox, add this as well:

```
input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. first the selector is ion-input but still that doesn't work for me. Any other solution to make the number input appear as textfields in firefox browser?

Comment: @fonzane it works, actually, maybe your styles are incapsulated. Try .wrapper::ng-deep input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button if you use Angular

Comment: @fonzane the above code works perfect when you add the ::ng-deep prefix just as suggested by Alex Link. However I have found that adding it to the global stylesheet does not work and I had to add it to the stylesheet of every component where I needed it

Comment: Can you please update the answer with the working ng-deep prefix. As per ionic 4 it doesn't seems to be working.